# Trying to apply filter with keyframes animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations, keyframe

What I'm after is essentially a fancy filter, you click a checkbox to show / hide a card type. The animation will whisk **all** the cards out of view, perform the showing / hiding logic out of view, then slide back in for only the **selected** card types.

I can get them to slide off, just can't suss out a good way to perform the show/hide and then slide back in - so that the actions can be repeated.

Any ideas? See the fiddle for a clearer picture!

```js
$(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function (){
        let arr_SessionsToShow = [];

        $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function () {
            arr_SessionsToShow.push($(this).val());
        });

        showHideSessions(arr_SessionsToShow);
    });
});

var showHideSessions = function (arr_SessionsToShow) {
    var cards = $('.card');
    const length = cards.length;
    let i = 0;

    setFiniteInterval(function () {
        if (arr_SessionsToShow.includes($(cards[i]).attr('data-type'))) {
                $(cards[i]).addClass('bounce-out-in');
        }
        else {
                $(cards[i]).addClass('bounce-out-left');
        }
        i++;
    }, 50, length, function () {
        //Something here for after perhaps?
    });
};

// sets interval for a defined number of repetition
var setFiniteInterval = function (callback, interval, reps, after) {
    let x = 0;
    let intervalId = window.setInterval(function () {
        callback();
        if (x++ === reps) {
            window.clearInterval(intervalId);

            if (after)
                after();
        }
    }, interval);
};
```

```css
.container{
  width:300px;
  overflow:hidden;
  display:inline-block;
}

ul{
   display:inline-block;
   vertical-align:top;
}

.card{
  width:100%;
  height: 100px;
}

.type1{
  background-color:red;
  color:#fff;
}

.type2{
  background-color:blue;
  color:#fff;
}

.type3{
  background-color:orange;
  color:blue;
}

.bounce-out-left{
    animation:bounce-out-left 0.5s ease-in; 
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}

.bounce-out-in{
    animation:bounce-out-in 1s ease-out;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}

@keyframes bounce-out-in{
    0% { margin-left: 0px;}

    10%{ margin-left: -10px;}

    50%{
        margin-left:400px;
    }

    90%{
        margin-left: -10px;
    }

    100%{
        margin-left:0px;
    }
}

@keyframes bounce-out-left{
    0%{
        margin-left:0px;
    }

    10%{
        margin-left:-10px;
    }

    98%{
        margin-left:400px;
    }

    99% {
        margin-left:400px;
        padding: 0px;
        height: 0px;
    }

    100% {
        margin-left: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        height: 0px;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="card type1" data-type="type1">Type 1</div>
  <div class="card type2" data-type="type2">Type 2</div>
  <div class="card type3" data-type="type3">Type 3</div>
  <div class="card type2" data-type="type2">Type 2</div>
  <div class="card type1" data-type="type1">Type 1</div>
  <div class="card type2" data-type="type2">Type 2</div>
  <div class="card type1" data-type="type1">Type 1</div>
  <div class="card type2" data-type="type2">Type 2</div>
  <div class="card type3" data-type="type3">Type 3</div>
</div>
<ul class="checkbox-list">
      <li>
          <label for="Type1">Show Type 1?:</label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="type1" checked="checked"/>
      </li>
      <li>
          <label for="Type1">Show Type 2?:</label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="type2" checked="checked"/>
      </li>
      <li>
          <label for="Type1">Show Type 3?:</label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="type3" checked="checked" />
      </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Theres a better way to handle the logic here:

By finding the cards by their classes, you can manipulate them a bit easier.

On a click of any checkbox, we can grab its value and see which class of cards its referring to. Then, we can check if the box is being checked or not and apply the correct CSS class. Importantly, we need to remove the opposite CSS class so it can happen again when we apply the class if the box is rechecked.

The timeout for hiding the card is so we can ensure the animation is done before hiding the card.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {

  $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function () {
    let classname = "." + $(this).val()
    console.log(classname)
      if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        $(classname).show()
        $(classname).addClass("bounce-out-in")
        $(classname).removeClass("bounce-out-left")

      } else {
        setTimeout(() => {
          $(classname).hide()
        }, 500)
        $(classname).addClass("bounce-out-left")
        $(classname).removeClass("bounce-out-in")
      }
  })

})
```

```css
.container{
  width:300px;
  overflow:hidden;
  display:inline-block;
}

ul{
   display:inline-block;
   vertical-align:top;
}

.card{
  width:100%;
  height: 100px;
}

.type1{
  background-color:red;
  color:#fff;
}

.type2{
  background-color:blue;
  color:#fff;
}

.type3{
  background-color:orange;
  color:blue;
}

.bounce-out-left{
    animation:bounce-out-left 0.5s ease-in; 
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}

.bounce-out-in{
    animation:bounce-out-in 1s ease-out;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}

@keyframes bounce-out-in{
    0% { margin-left: 0px;}

    10%{ margin-left: -10px;}

    50%{
        margin-left:400px;
    }

    90%{
        margin-left: -10px;
    }

    100%{
        margin-left:0px;
    }
}

@keyframes bounce-out-left{
    0%{
        margin-left:0px;
    }

    10%{
        margin-left:-10px;
    }

    98%{
        margin-left:400px;
    }

    99% {
        margin-left:400px;
        padding: 0px;
        height: 0px;
    }

    100% {
        margin-left: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        height: 0px;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="index.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="card type1" data-type="type1">Type 1</div>
  <div class="card type2" data-type="type2">Type 2</div>
  <div class="card type3" data-type="type3">Type 3</div>
  <div class="card type2" data-type="type2">Type 2</div>
  <div class="card type1" data-type="type1">Type 1</div>
  <div class="card type2" data-type="type2">Type 2</div>
  <div class="card type1" data-type="type1">Type 1</div>
  <div class="card type2" data-type="type2">Type 2</div>
  <div class="card type3" data-type="type3">Type 3</div>
</div>
<ul class="checkbox-list">
      <li>
          <label for="Type1">Show Type 1?:</label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="type1" checked="checked"/>
      </li>
      <li>
          <label for="Type1">Show Type 2?:</label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="type2" checked="checked"/>
      </li>
      <li>
          <label for="Type1">Show Type 3?:</label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="type3" checked="checked" />
      </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Good effort - there's one issue here though. When re-selecting the checkbox the cards flash in before the animation kicks in. My idea was to move all of the cards out and only move the selected back in to get around this :)